# How to pass value from one function to another

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing

Hello I want to pass value "valuey" from method veikia() to method
checkButtonClick(). I`m newby on Java so sorry if this question is already answered, because I do not understand:)

Have a nice day :)

Here is my code:

```
public class ListViewCheckboxesActivity extends Activity {

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    PrekesDBController controller = new PrekesDBController(this);

    //private Context mContext;
    ScrollView sv;
    TextView infotext;
    CheckBox check;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Spinner spinner2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // mContext = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main123);

       // mContext = this;


        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();

        checkButtonClick();

        veikia();

    }


  public String veikia() {
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data2 = controller.getpavadinimas();
      String valuey = "";
      for (int kl = 0; kl < data2.size(); kl++) {
          spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner11);

          ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myscroll123);
          LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinearLayout123);

          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.naujasuzsakymailist123, null);


          ll.addView(view);

          //sikna = int kl;
          Spinner jopapa = new Spinner(this);
          jopapa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner11);
          jopapa.setId(kl);

          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("1");
          list.add("2");
          list.add("3");
          list.add("4");
          list.add("5");
          list.add("6");
          list.add("7");
          list.add("8");
          list.add("9");
          list.add("10");
          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
          dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          jopapa.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
          valuey = String.valueOf(jopapa.getSelectedItem());
          System.out.println(valuey);
      }


     return valuey;
  }

    public void checkButtonClick() {


        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

                ArrayList<Country> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;
                for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++){
                    Country country = countryList.get(i);
                    if(country.isSelected()){
                        responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: `public void checkButtonClick() {  String s = veikia();  .....}`

Comment: It will be fine, but it run my function again, I need only value of "valuey"

Comment: with that , you now just need to call `checkButtonClick();`  inside `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the return value of `veikia()` to `checkButtonClick()` when you call it:

```
public String veikia() {
    ...
    return valuey;
}

// Added parameter valuey
public void checkButtonClick(String valuey) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Call checkButtonClick() with the parameter valuey returned from veikia()
    checkButtonClick(veikia());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your `checkButtonClick`method from:

```
public void checkButtonClick(){...}
```

to:

```
public void checkButtonClick(String myString) { 
  // Use the value of myString here
}
```

And then on your `onCreate` method, instead of calling:

```
checkButtonClick();

veikia();
```

Call the functions in reverse order, like:

```
String valuey = veikia();
checkButtonClick(valuey)
```

**EDIT:**

In order to have access to `valuey` from inside a method you're overriding, like `OnClickListener.onClick(View v)` you will have to define `valuey` as a member variable. The final result would look something like this:

```
public class ListViewCheckboxesActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  private String valuey;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    valuey = veikia();
  }

  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      // do something with valuey, for example print it to the logger
      Log.d("TAG", valuey);
  }
}
```

Comment: And how now to pass that value to onClick(View v)?

Comment: Since you're overriding `onClick` you can't change it's signature. What you have to do is to define `valuey` as a member variable and then use it inside the `onClick` method

Comment: and how I can do it? can you write me a example?

Comment: @RytisVanagas I updated my answer to show how it is done

Comment: In your specific case, since you're declaring `OnClickListener` as an anonymous class you should remove `implements View.OnClickListener`